# Button click event in Swing

Tags: java, swing, chess

I have created chess board using `JButton` and for pieces I used ASCII values.

I added `ActionListener` to all the buttons. When i clicked source(first) button `actionPerformed` event is called and i stored the value of the button in the variable.

But the problem is when i clicked the destination button `actionPerformed` event is called and value is replaced with source button value.

I want source button value and destination button value in different variables. How it is possible?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
{
    JButton o = (JButton) ae.getSource();
    value = o.getText();
}
```

Comment: i have 64 buttons.It is difficult to implement 64 ActionListners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you need 2 variables to store the two values and a third variable to tell you which click is happening.

```
     if(isSource){
         source = o.getText();
         isSource = false;
     }else{
         destination = o.getText();
         isSource = true;
     }
```

This way, on the first click you know the value of the source, and on teh second click you know the value of the destination. Then on the next click it is a source again etc.

Comment: After if else block i have to send both source and destination values to another boolean method.If the method returns true i have to modify both source and destination button values. If i am using the same object is it possible to change both button values?

Comment: Yes. But we will need to see more of your code to understand what approach you are taking. But what you are saying could work.

Comment: if(flag)
    {
    JButton o=(JButton) ae.getSource();
    src=o.getText();
    flag=false;
    }
    else
    {
    JButton ob=(JButton) ae.getSource();
    dst=ob.getText();
    flag=true;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, src+dst);
    }
I tried like this but,If flag is true both blocks are exicuting.
I don't know whats wrong with the code..

Comment: You need to move the JOptionPane part outside of the if statement. Put it after the closing }

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage the state of your application in some way. At the first click, the state of the application is that it waits for information of the source of the move. Then it waits for information of the destination of the move.

You could create an enum in your class like this:

```
enum ActionState {
    SOURCE,
    DESTINATION
}
```

And store the action state and the button variables as members of the class:

```
ActionState state = SOURCE;

String source;
String destination;
```

Then actionPerformed would be like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
{
    JButton o = (JButton) ae.getSource();
    String value = o.getText();

    if (state == SOURCE){
        source = value;
        state = DESTINATION;
    }
    else if (state == DESTINATION){
        destination = value;
        state = SOURCE;
        // you probably want to call something here to perform the move itself.
    }
}
```

Instead of an enum, you could just use a boolean to represent your state. But using an enum allows for more extensibility if you need other states in the future.